# Calendar overlay: Is there any way to delete an event that is in a calendar overlay?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, calendar

I have a Calendar with several views on the same list.  These views filter based on a choice column and are used in an overlay to show each choice as a different color.  My problem is that the delete button (show on the ribbon with the calendar.aspx) is grayed out when looking at the overlay.  WHy is this since all the views are of the same calendar list?  Is there any way to allow delete of an event from a calendar overlay (other than from the dispform.aspx)?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you see is the default behaviour and it cannot be tweaked.

Not only the delete button, all other buttons for the event including the "set alert on this item" button gets disabled. You will only be able to edit and delete events in your master calendar when you have a calendar overlay.

You can click on the quick launch menu links which displays the different views incorporated for your calendar overlay and could add or delete events for each views on the respective pages.

You can always think about writing a custom Ribbon button, which deletes the calendar event item(similar to a custom list item). But you have to decide whether the requirement is worth it.